# switch focus from desktop app to the chromedriver window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So i have been stuck with this for a while. I have built a desktop application which launches a chrome window using chromedriver. However the focus remains on the application and the chrome window is always in the background. I want to bring it to the foreground so the user could interact with the chrome window (enter input etc).
I have tried using the following :

`driver.switchTo();
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");`

But the application always remains on top. Is there a way possible to switch to the browser window? Thank you.

Comment: if you are on java, did you try switching using windows handles like below. for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

Comment: I used `driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());`
But my application is still the top window and the chrome window is the second window right behind my app. I want the user to interact with the chrome window without him taking the extra step of clicking on the window manually to bring it on top.

Comment: can you try this. driver.manage().window().maximize()

Comment: @minion tried your suggestion. It maximizes but is still not the top window.  is there any way of sending my application in the background? i used javafx to build it